# How do ASP.NET Identity and Thinktecture.IdentityModel library relate to each other?

Tags: .net, security, asp.net-web-api, thinktecture-ident-model

I've just started to implement security in our web api service (mostly as a research endeavor).
And ran across new [ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity) and quite mature [Thinktecture.IdentityModel](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.45/wiki) library.

As I'm not experienced with this whole bunch of authentication/authorization mechanisms it's quite confusing. Now I cannot say whether these libraries are about the same or othogonal to each other.

I would appreciate any clarification of which one should be used and when.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, ASP.NET Identity is an identity management framework (storing user account data, like usernames and passwords). This article goes into depth on the features and design of ASP.NET Identity: http://brockallen.com/2013/10/20/the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-of-asp-net-identity/

Thinktecture.IdentityModel is a security helper library for many missing features in WIF/Claims, ASP.NET, MVC and Web API. An example is security token processing in Web API v1 -- Web API had nothing like this. Another example is CORS support -- again, in Web API v1 there was no help for that.

They serve two different purposes.

Comment: Thanks. And a little offtopic: I can find nothing concerning ACLs. Everyone usually talks about claims or role-based security. Do you have any experience with ACLs? May be some libraries?

Comment: Well, there are not a lot of permissions libraries out there (at least that I'm aware of). WIF/.NET has its own approach with the ClaimsAuthorizationManager, but it still leaves you to implement the logic.